# PlayFramework Navigation Bar for Video Site

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework

So i am trying to make a dynamic navigation bar in play with the following code in my main.scala.html file:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/DCicon.jpg")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.Assets.versioned("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.Assets.versioned("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="page-container">

    <!-- top navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/DCicon.jpg")">DirtyChimp</a>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">@title</a></li>
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.categories">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>              
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- main area -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <h1>Shrink Width to Collapse Sidebar</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in nisi eu arcu tempus vehicula. 
            Nulla faucibus cursus metus in sagittis. Nunc elit leo, imperdiet in ligula in, euismod varius est. 
            Aenean pellentesque lorem a porttitor placerat. Vestibulum placerat nunc ac rutrum fringilla. Donec 
            arcu leo, tempus adipiscing volutpat id, congue in purus. Pellentesque scelerisque mattis nibh vel 
            semper. Sed a risus purus. Fusce pulvinar, velit eget rhoncus facilisis, enim elit vulputate nisl, a 
            euismod diam metus eu enim. Nullam congue justo vitae justo accumsan, sit amet malesuada nulla sagittis. 
            Nam neque tellus, tristique in est vel, sagittis congue turpis. Aliquam nulla lacus, laoreet dapibus 
            odio vitae, posuere volutpat magna. Nam pulvinar lacus in sapien feugiat, sit amet vestibulum enim 
            eleifend. Integer sit amet ante auctor, lacinia sem quis, consectetur nulla.</p>

        </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 main -->
    </div><!--/.row-->
  </div><!--/.container-->
</div><!--/.page-container-->
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

I am fairly new to using scala and very experienced with java. I am trying to figure out how to make this nav bar dynamic as you navigate from page to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the additional content for the nav-bar when you compose the template like this:

```
@(title: String, navBar: Html = HtmlFormat.empty)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
<!-- top navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/DCicon.jpg")">DirtyChimp</a>
       @navBar
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
...
@content
</body>
</html>
```

The other templates can be created like this:

```
@(title: String)

@navBarContent = {
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
}
@main(title, navBar = navBarContent) {
  <h1>Page with custom navBar!</h1>
}
```

I'm assuming that the first template is called `main.scala.html`.

Comment: where exactly would i be putting the navBarContent = {}. I guess thats what I'm confused about. Would i be making a separate file for it @marceloemanoel

Comment: Yes its another template, the one that your action will call.

like this:
    def customPage() = Action { implicit request =>
       Ok(views.html.customPage("custom page title")
    }

Comment: would the template be called navBarContent.scala.html?

Comment: you can call it whatever name you want :)

Comment: You should put the navBarContent = {} on each page that you want it to be different.

Comment: You can even omit it and the template will work since some default value is given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100429/discussion-between-clr45-and-marceloemanoel).